# How can I increase the spacing between the buffer and the top part of the frame?

Tags: init-file, window

I'd like to add a margin to the top of the window so that it's not so close to the top part of the frame.

Here's what it looks like currently (arrow indicates where I'd like to add extra margin):
[image]

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Layout-Parameters.html#Layout-Parameters), it can't be set individually at the moment. You can play with `internal-border-width` which would change *all* the borders inside the frame. That's what setting it to 7 gives:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(internal-border-width . 7))
```

[image: X buffer, internal-border-width set to 7]

Maybe you'll find a value which would add enough space on top and at the same time small enough that it doesn't affect the sides too much.

Comment: It would be a decent workaround but because I'm using tabbar it creates the space above the tabs not in between the tabs and text I'm guessing it would be hard to add a margin in that specific place. Unless I figure out how to add extra line height only to the top line of text.

Answer (score 1):

The `tabbar` package uses an obscure emacs features called the `header-line` to display the tab bar. This `header-line` is an extra line of text shown at the top of a buffer, just as the `mode-line` is shown at the bottom. The text in this line is rendered using the `tabbar-default` face, so you could edit it and change some parameters to customize the look of the tab bar. You could change its font size, or change the font used, for example. Perhaps that will get you close to what you want.

On the other hand, you can't change the line spacing for an individual face, that has to be done for the buffer as a whole. (Curiously, the `line-spacing` variable isn't used for the `header-line` or the `mode-line`, so you can put extra space between all the lines of the buffer except these two.)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a minor mode related to this which is now available on MELPA:

[TopSpace](https://github.com/trevorpogue/topspace) - Recenter line 1 with scrollable upper margin/padding

[image: topspace]